# Tweepy to sqllite3

Tags: python, sqlite, tweepy

I'm trying to do a project to that involves creating a simple class to write tweets to a database...

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self,status):

        conn = sqlite3.connect('tweets.sqlite')
        curs = conn.cursor()
        curs.execute("CREATE TABLE TWEETS(txt text, author text, created int, source text)")


        print ("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s" % (status.text, 
                          status.author.screen_name, 
                          status.created_at, 
                          status.source))


sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener(api))
sapi.filter(track=['#twitter'])
```

But whenever I try to run it, nothing happens.  If I could provide an error message I would but the cell in my notebook runs for a second then stops.  Any thoughts?

Comment: so it works and seems like `on_status` has never been called

Comment: following the [docs](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/streaming_how_to.html?highlight=on_status#step-1-creating-a-streamlistener) there is no need to pass `api` argument to `CustomStreamListener` initializer

Comment: does simple example from documentation work?